# How to send message directly to friend in Facebook Messenger for Android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-messenger

I am developing an android app. I would like to be able to send a message programmatically directly to a specific friend in Messenger App. I'd like this to happen without requiring the user to select a friend.

For example, if user A has friend B, and has sent a message to friend B in the past, I'd like the app to remember friend B. Is it possible to directly invoke and send message "hello" to friend B from Android app?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apis-and-sdks

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger/android

Comment: not possible and not allowed according to the platform policy (autoposting/-sending, prefilling).

Comment: Thanks @luschn but is it possible if the user grants some kind of permission to allow the app to send a message on the user's behalf?

Comment: no, there is no way at all. but it does not really matter, because, again: it is not allowed to prefill or autosend.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible.

According to Facebook policy, it is not allowed to auto-post / send / or pre-fill messages to friends.